# How to sort a list of tuples with by the second column of a nested list?

Tags: python, list, sorting, tuples

I have the following list of tuples in which each tuple consists of a list followed by two strings. I wish to sort the list of tuples based on the second column of the nested list within the tuple.
example array:

```
array = [([45, 56, '-'], 'CGUCAUAAAGUA', 'MKYC'), ([24, 38, '-'], 'GUAAGGUUUGCCGUA', 'MPFGM'), ([6, 26, '-'], 'CCCGGGGUACACAGUAAUGUA', 'M**HMGP')]
```

expected output:

```
sortedTuples = [([6, 26, '-'], 'CCCGGGGUACACAGUAAUGUA', 'M**HMGP'), ([24, 38, '-'], 'GUAAGGUUUGCCGUA', 'MPFGM'),  ([45, 56, '-'], 'CGUCAUAAAGUA', 'MKYC')]
```

as `26 < 38 < 56`.

I have tried the code:

```
sortedTuples = [sorted(list1, key = lambda x: x[1]) for list1, str1, str2 in array]
```

and I am getting the error:

```
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `sorted(array,key=lambda x:x[0][1])`

Comment: Thank you, this worked. I will read up on how to use lambda for the future!

Answer (score 0):

The following code may work for you,

code:

```
def sort1(val):
    return val[0][1]

list1= [([45, 56, '-'], 'CGUCAUAAAGUA', 'MKYC'), ([24, 38, '-'], 'GUAAGGUUUGCCGUA', 'MPFGM'), ([6, 26, '-'], 'CCCGGGGUACACAGUAAUGUA', 'M**HMGP')]
list1.sort(key=sort1)
print(list1)
```

output:

```
[([6, 26, '-'], 'CCCGGGGUACACAGUAAUGUA', 'M**HMGP'), ([24, 38, '-'], 'GUAAGGUUUGCCGUA', 'MPFGM'), ([45, 56, '-'], 'CGUCAUAAAGUA', 'MKYC')]
```